Retrieving Images from Oracle 12C into BIP Report
I want to create report in BIP to show me customer images form SIGTEXT column in Oracle 12c, Like Displaying in Oracle front app but when I want to insert image in BIP I face to some error.
SELECT sg.SIGNAME,
       mg.CIFID,
       decode(mg.IMGTYPE, 'I', 'Image', 'S', 'Signature') image_type,
       mg.SIGTEXT
  FROM table2 mg, table1 sg 
 WHERE mg.CIFID = '02222002'
 and  mg.CIFID = sg.CIFID


Error Screenshot| https://i.sstatic.net/M64WCc2p.png)

"I face to some error." What error? Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with all the relevant information including the complete error message.

This is the error which is already attached : Uncaught Error Failed to load: io/designer//inline-preview-dynamic-image

I want to show the customer's photo from the backend (database) in the frontend  (BIP application) report.
